# Mongodb If add new Index to already existing Collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I would like to know if I add new index the older documents of a collection will be indexed as I added this new index rule?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, all documents including existing one will be indexed. Once you create an index, MongoDB builds index from scratch.

It's recommended to create index during off peak hours if you have very large collection as it will block all other operations on collection being indexed, unless it's not a background index operation.

see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#behaviors