# Mongo db Indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am using mongodb as the database for my ongoing project since last 3 months. When I am starting with mongodb, I didn’t have a clear idea about Indexing. So curranty it does not have at least one indexing in the whole database. Now it get abnormally slow when I querying data even from two thousand documents. Now I hope to make table indexes from Robo 3T mongo database management tool and I got two questions.

1. If I create indexes on my current database, will it create indexes for all available data? Or effects for new records only?
2. In some queries I am using more than one fields of a specific collection with $match to filter out data and some using only one fields of the same collection. My question is creating compound indexes and also single indexes to match both cases is the best practice or not?

Comment: 1. index is field oriented, only index the fields that you frequently use them as query condition; 2. if query happens on 2+ fields almost all the time, you can consider adding a compound index, otherwise consider single index.

Comment: Your "question" is actually "two questions". That should have been pretty clear when you thought to start adding dot points. So to summarize. 1. Is a question asked many times before which basically means pointing you to the duplicate since we really don't need it answered again. 2. Is actually far too broad a topic, and would be a close reason for the question by itself. This kind of leaves you with looking at 2 and being more specific about a single use case if you want to keep this on-topic.

Comment: btw, 2000 documents is a very small size to mongodb even for full collection scan,  please take a look at your query design if there's any inefficient design or implementation.

Comment: 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757200/mongodb-if-add-new-index-to-already-existing-collection 2: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/

Comment: Also, for 2: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/